# Getting a variable from a certain pattern

Tags: php, variables, preg-replace, pattern-matching

I need to save the number between every pair of curly brackets as a variable.

```
{2343} -> $number
echo $number;
Output = 2343
```

I don't know how to do the '->' part.

I've found a similar function, but it simply removes the curly brackets and does nothing else.

```
preg_replace('#{([0-9]+)}#','$1', $string);
```

Is there any function I can use?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: I'm afraid it does slightly, especially after what I've seen on this board in the past. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match) with a capture:

```
$subject = "{2343}";
$pattern = '/\{(\d+)\}/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {2343}
    [1] => 2343
)
```

The `$matches` array will contain the result at index 1 if it is found, so:

```
if(!empty($matches) && isset($matches[1)){
    $number = $matches[1];
}
```

If your input string can contain many numbers, then use preg_match_all:

```
$subject = "{123} {456}";
$pattern = '/\{(\d+)\}/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {123}
            [1] => {456}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '{1234}';
preg_replace('#{([0-9]+)}#e','$number = $1;', $string);
echo $number;
```